# AWS RUM throws Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a SaaS system up and running on Elastic Beanstalk, load balanced. I also have a non-load balanced setup running on Elastic Beanstalk where I upload and test the system before pushing it to my production environment.

I decided to as RUM today, and created two app monitors, one for my test environment and one for production. Same account, same user. When I run the RUM code on the test environment with the test app monitor code I have no issues, everything works.

But, when I change over to the production code (I remove the previous test app monitor code) and upload to production, it throws an error: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity

The user I am using has full access to everything, so what could be causing this?

````
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}```

Same user has created both environments, the RUM app monitors etc. I am at a loss to why the server rejects it on the production environment but is fine on the test environment?

[![Error in browser][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1nT9.png
````